# How to set label to multiple line when screen size decrease in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating desktop application using wpf. I have grid in which row is divided in three columns. When the screen size is larger all working well. but when I decrease screen size. label get cropped. I have attached both the scenario

Larger Screen:http://prntscr.com/8kxuas
Small Screen:http://prntscr.com/8kxufe

Here is the code for grid:

```
<Window x:Class="CharunOptics.Search"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Charun Optics" Height="800px" Width="1600px" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Search: (Name or Contact)" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" Margin="25,0,25,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"  Grid.Row="0" Name="TxtName"/>
            <Button x:Name="BtnSearch"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Search" FontSize="20" Click="BtnSearch_Click" Margin="32"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="DtGrid" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryFont}" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Is it possible to set label in multiple line when it is overflow just like HTML?

Comment: TextWrapping=Wrap is not available with Label. Should I give it to column?

Comment: Then use a TextBlock ?  Why crowd it in the middle like that if you don't have space?  Why give up a margin of 25 if you are running out of space?

Comment: Margin is required for giving space between label and textbox. If I don't give it, they will look ugly.

Comment: And what about only using the middle?

Comment: Ok. I don't know about middle. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for it. I've change the Lable to TextBlock, as lable don't have textwrapping property.

Thanks to @Frisbee for your advise

```
<TextBlock Text="Search: (Name or Contact)" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

first:

wpf Label dose not support text wrapping. a better idea is to use text wrapping

a better idea is to use TextBlock which supports text wrapping.

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Your huge text here</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just set the width/ height- property to `Auto` (it's the default value). That will set the size of the label base of the screen size.

Comment: sorry no luck. I think Height and width auto works for HTML not for WPF.